# How should I deal with the message "Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated..."?

Tags: php

I'm seeing the following message on my site, what should I do?

> Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\wamp\www\cidoc.gov.mz\modules\mod_swmenupro\functions.php on line 2542

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list of deprecated functions and the replacement functions

```
Function replacements POSIX PCRE 
ereg_replace() => preg_replace() 
ereg() => preg_match() 
eregi_replace() => preg_replace() 
eregi() => preg_match() 
split() => preg_split() 
spliti() => preg_split() 
sql_regcase() => No equivalent
```

user `preg_match()` instead of `eregi()`

Comment: thnk u for the list, actually i had 2 problem eregi_replace too and i didnt see that thank u, it works but i use @ before eregi_replace.....

Comment: Preg_match is your better option.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the function "eregi()" that was [deprecated in PHP 5.3.0](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php)

You can

a. downgrade your php version (not recommended) or

b. use stristr(). The manual has a comment that says this you can use to replace the code in your files:

> because eregi is not recommended after php 5, you can replaced it 
>   with `stristr` if just for simple search.
>
> For editors with regular expression function:
>
> ```
> eregi\(([^,]*),([^)]*)\)
> stristr(\2,\1)
> ```

I have not tried this.

Comment: thank u, that works fine but i use @ before eregi() and it works good too, when i use stristr() i have to change many lines where have eregi()...but thnk u